# Get number of times a number will multiply itself with another until reach a certain limit

Tags: javascript, math

I can get the number of times a number will multiply itself with another until reach a certain limit:

```
var velocity = -5.706875;
var friction = 0.9925;
var limit = 0
var times = 0;

while (Math.floor(Math.abs(velocity)*10) > limit) {
    velocity *= friction;
    times += 1;
}
// times = 538
```

Is there a way to get times without a loop?
Tried `Math.log(5.706875, 0.9925)` but it gives another result.

Comment: Can always do something recursive I suppose: http://jsfiddle.net/s58s9fcL/

Comment: @timeJV Not much change from a loop but thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there you are:

```
times = Math.ceil(Math.log(-0.1/velocity)/Math.log(friction));
```

Edit:

Actually, taking into account `limit` var, it would be:

```
times = Math.ceil(Math.log(-(0.1+limit/10)/velocity)/Math.log(friction));
```

Comment: Great! It actually does 538. Thanks Ipg

Answer (score 1):

@lpg has provided the correct answer. To clarify a bit:

First of all, `Math.floor(Math.abs(velocity)*10) > 0` is a roundabout way of saying `Math.abs(velocity) > 0.1`, since you want the process to stop as soon as `v * 10` is less than 1 (or in other words, `v` is less than 0.1).

So we can start with that. Your iterative process continually determines velocity as `v = vi * f ^ n`, where `n` is the number of iterations, so we have:

```
abs(v * f ^ n) > abs(0.1)
```

And we want to solve for the value of `n` that will make both sides equal, making it the threshold point.

In this case, we know that `f ^ n` is positive because `f` is positive, and we know that `v` is negative, which means that `v * f ^ n` is negative, and `abs(v * f ^ n)` is equal to `-(v * f ^ n)`.

Step-by-step, we can do:

```
-(v * f ^ n)     = 0.1             // start

-1 * (v * f ^ n) = 0.1             // -x = -1 * x

(-1 * v) * f ^ n = 0.1             // associative property

-v * f ^ n        = 0.1            // -1 * v = -v

- f ^ n           = 0.1 / v        // divide both sides by v

f ^ n             = -0.1 / v       // negate both sides          

log(f ^ n)        = log(-0.1 / v)  // log both sides

n * log(f)        = log(-0.1 / v)  // take the exponent out of the log

n                 = log(-0.1 / v) / log(f)  // divide both sides by log(f)
```

At that point, it's just a simple calculation, rounding up as needed to account for the last iteration:

```
var n = Math.ceil(Math.log(-0.1 / velocity) / Math.log(friction));
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will have to look further in to this.